# Disable Firefox search when site down

Tags: windows, firefox

Is it possible to disable the automatic search when you type a full URL in the location bar and the site is not reachable?

I can't figure out the name of the feature so I can find more info about... I'll give an example:

1. I type http://tmp/ in the location bar to load a local development site
2. My local Apache is down so the site is unreachable
3. Firefox loads http://www.tmp.com
4. I start Apache
5. I have to type again the original URL

This is true even when Apache cannot find another site: the last attempted URL remains in the location bar.

Comment: I have no idea if it can be turned of, but it's not search. Firefox will automatically try to add .com and www. to the URL.

Comment: Your remark allowed me to find http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/domain-guessing.html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records, the feature is called "domain guessing":

http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/domain-guessing.html

The link explains how to disable it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to prevent this question from being bumped to the front page again.